# Solving $28^x \equiv 2 \pmod{43}$

Tags: number-theory

> How do we solve $28^x \equiv 2 \pmod{43}$?

I know there are not generally efficient methods for computing the discrete logarithm which are defined for an invertible $a$ modulo $q$ by $$a \equiv t^x \pmod{q}, \quad 0 \leq x \leq q-1,$$ but I was wondering if there was a way to compute it efficiently here.

Comment: Sorry, did you want a general algorithm or something that works just for this problem, where works is defined as a human can do it easily?

Comment: I don't think so, the order of $28$ is $42$ and the order of $2$ is $21$. So it could really be any even number, and I think each one is as good a guess as any other.

Comment: @Hwai-RayTung A way a human can do it easily.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling The set of all such $x$ can be determined to be $x \equiv 39 \pmod{42}$.

Comment: @JohnRyan I meant every guess is as good as any other before knowing the actual number.

Answer (score 3):

We try to make $\,2\equiv 45\equiv \color{#c00}5\cdot \color{#0a0}3^2\,$ using factors of $\,3\,$ and $\,5\,$ from small powers of $\,28.\,$

$\qquad\qquad  28^3\equiv 22\equiv -\color{#0a0}3\cdot 7$

$\qquad\qquad  \color{#c00}{28^5}\equiv \color{#c00}5$

$\qquad\qquad 28^7\equiv 7$

So we have $\,\color{#c00}5\,$ and we can make  $\ {-}\color{#0a0}3\equiv 28^3/28^7\equiv \color{#0a0}{28^{-4}}$

Therefore $\ 2\equiv \color{#c00}5\cdot (\color{#0a0}{-3})^2 \equiv  \color{#c00}{28^5}(\color{#0a0}{28^{-4}})^2\equiv 28^{-3}\equiv 28^{39},\ $ by $\,28^{42}\equiv 1\,$ by Fermat.

Comment: It should also be noted that the order of $28$ modulo $43$ is $42$.

Comment: @JohnRyan But we don't need that above.

Comment: How then can you say this is the set of all possible solutions?

Comment: @JohnRyan If you need all solutions then yes, you could use that

Comment: Your algorithm is excellent but how to generalise it  I mean how to find some other discrete logarithm, such as $28^x \equiv 30 \pmod {42}$.

Comment: @Zack Many algorithms in number theory use this idea. You pick a "basis" of small primes, then you do linear algebra on the exponent vectors of these primes to find a solution once you have enough relations.

Comment: This is very nice.

Comment: Yes, this is good. The method is known as [index calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_calculus_algorithm), and is one of the techniques in working out discrete log problems. It works equally well in some other finite fields. For example in $\Bbb{F}_2[x]/(p(x))$ you use irreducible low degree polynomials the same way as selected small primes were used here.

Answer (score 0):

Some enumerating is inevitable:

Notice that

$28^7 \equiv 7 \pmod{43}$

$28^4 \equiv 14 \pmod{43}$

Let $x = 4k+7w$ since [Bézout's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem)

Now $28^x \equiv 28^{4k+7w} \equiv  2 ^k 7^{k+w} \equiv 2 \pmod{43}$

$\implies k \equiv 1 \pmod {42}$ and $k+w \equiv 0 \pmod {42}$

$ \implies k \equiv 1 \pmod {42}$ and $w \equiv -1 \equiv 41 \pmod {42}$

$\implies x \equiv 39 \pmod{42}$

EDIT: Why do I come up with such idea?

Firstly, I write a program running all the logarithm with base $28$. Here is my program written in C plus plus:

```
int u = 1;
for(int i = 1;i<=42;++i)
{
        u*= 28;
        u%=43;
        printf("%d ",u);
}
```

All the related discrete logarithm  listed here (i.e. the output of my program):

```
28 10 22 14 5 11 7 24 27 25 12 35 34 6 39 17 3 41 30 23 42 15 33 21 29 38 32 36 19 16 18 31 8 9 37 4 26 40 2 13 20 1
```

And notice that $28 = 2 \times 7$, so I will try to find the position the least number which can be decomposed into $2$ or $7$ or spontaneous.

And I ascertain that position $7$ and $4$ satisfying the condition.

Answer (score 0):

We move from $28$ to $5$ to facilitate calculations (btw, both numbers are primitive roots modulo $43$). One has $5^{17}=28$ so we have to solve the equivalent equation $$5^{17x}\equiv 2\pmod{43}$$ Calculating first $$5^w\equiv 2\pmod{43}$$ we find $w=33$ hence $$5^{17x}=5^{33}\Rightarrow  5^{17x}=5^{33}\cdot 5^{42y}\space  (\text{ Fermat’s little theorem })$$
We have then the diophantine equation $$17x-42y=33$$ whose general solution is $$(x,y)=(42n+39,17n+15)$$ For $n=0$ one has the answer $\color{red}{x=39}$